# How to resolve NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

When I click on the "create User" button I get the following error:

```
Avatar Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
```

My code snippets are given below:

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Paperclip gem for managing file uploads
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:x64_mingw, :mingw, :mswin]
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Original Avatar</th>
      <th>Thumbnail Avatar</th>
      <th>Resume Filename</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <!-- display the avatar in both the original size and the thumbnail size -->
        <td><%= image_tag user.avatar.url %></td>
        <td><%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:thumb) %></td>

        <!-- show the filename for the resume -->
        <td><%= user.resume_file_name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
```

views/users/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New user</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

views/users/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <!-- Upload your attachments via a simple file_fields in the form -->
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :avatar %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :resume %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :resume %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to action: 'index', notice: 'User was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new', alert: 'User could not be created' 
    end
  end

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar, :resume)
    end
end
```

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
#specify that the avatar is a paperclip file attachment
  #specify additional styles that you want to use in views or eslewhere
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {:thumb => "100x100>"}

  #specify that the resume is a paperclip file attachment
  has_attached_file :resume

end
```

config/environment/development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16'
  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

I have already installed `ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16` on my system. I am using rails-4 and ruby-1.9.3.

I would appreciate help in finding the solution. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is caused by the API change in Cocaine 4 which Paperclip has not caught up to yet. Try using the earlier version of Cocaine by inserting this line into your Gemfile:

gem "cocaine", "= 0.3.2"

Comment: Hello Dipak,No its again gave the same error message which has explained above after adding gem "cocaine", "= 0.3.2" in Gemfile and ran the command bundle update.Any other idea to solve this error.Please share with me.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed since paperclip 3.3: github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1038

Comment: As of January 2, 2014, Paperclip 3.5.2 requires cocaine ~> 0.5.3

Comment: Dipak,I have already done small changes over your comment.i did gem "cocaine", "~> 0.5.3" and also did bundle update..but nothing new error was same.Anyway thanks..